# CloudMQTT API Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, api, mqtt, guzzle

I have a problem with translating curl to guzzle request.
In docs to create a user i just need to post:

```
$ curl -XPOST -d '{"username":"test", "password":"super_secret_password"}' -H         "Content-Type:application/json" -u "$CLOUDMQTT_USER:$CLOUDMQTT_PASSWORD"     https://api.cloudmqtt.com/user
```

In my project I cannot use curl, so i use guzzle:

```
$client = new Client();

$res = $client->post('https://api.cloudmqtt.com/user', ['auth' =>  ['xxx', 'xxx'], 'body' => ["username"=>"user", "password"=>"super_secret_password"]]);
```

And user is created, I can see new user on the users list on panel, but server is responsing with 500 when creating the user. What am I doing wrong? Maybe my guzzle request is wrong format? I have no idea

https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-api.html link to API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match up your Guzzle request to the curl request, although I can't say for sure that will solve your 500 error:

```
$client = new Client([
    'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ]
]);

$response = $client->post('https://api.cloudmqtt.com/user',
    [
        'auth' =>  ['xxx', 'xxx'],
        'body' => json_encode(
            [
                "username"=>"user",
                "password"=>"super_secret_password"
            ]
        )
    ]
);
```

The differences here include setting the Content-Type header and also encoding the body to json instead of an array (which may not have an effect here?).

EDIT:
It looks like the `json` parameter will automatically set the header and `json_encode` the body for you:

```
$client = new Client();

$response = $client->post('https://api.cloudmqtt.com/user',
    [
        'auth' =>  ['xxx', 'xxx'],
        'json' =>
            [
                "username"=>"user",
                "password"=>"super_secret_password"
            ]
    ]
);
```

[Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/clients.html)

Comment: cURL error 18: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining, still 500 :(

Comment: Was that from Guzzle?

Comment: I've slightly modified my answer but it shouldn't be functionally any different from my original. Try it out regardless, just in case.

Comment: Wow man, that hepled me soo much! It responses 200 and creates user!

Comment: Welp, this is definitely one of those "I don't know why it worked, but it did" moments.

Comment: I have really no idea, why 'body' doesn't work well, but when I putted 'json' it works correctly, the user is creating, it responds with 409 when the username is in use

Comment: @MaoStream if you use body, you will have to set the headers correctly for the json data that is the body. If you use json, it will set the headers for you.

Comment: @srayhunter Thanks